# AndroidX Spinner not displaying list

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm trying to integrate a Spinner into my Layout (it was working well before AndroidX migration).

here is the code:

```
Spinner spinner_nationalite;
String[] data_nationalite = {"","Française","Suisse","Belge","Allemande"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
spinner_nationalite = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.update_spinner_nationalite);
ArrayAdapter adapter_nationalite = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item, data_nationalite);
adapter_nationalite.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner_nationalite.setAdapter(adapter_nationalite);

spinner_nationalite.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Log.d("KAIROSAPP","Nationalite selected: "+data_nationalite[i]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Here is the spinner_dropdown_item.xml

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
android:textSize="17sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

And finally the Layout XML

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/update_spinner_nationalite"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView55"/>
```

I can see the Spinner but there are no data listed and no dropdown visible on click.

I also tried to use AppCompatSpinner from androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner and also use android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item instead of the custom one but I have the same result.

For sure I'm missing something....

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem on my side. I ran your code successfully on AndroidX project.

[image]

Comment: maybe you should start a new project and try again.

Comment: I understood the problem, my code is working fine in a fresh new Activity but I'm calling this code from a Layout which is dispayed thanks to getLayoutInflater().inflate. I think I"ll use Fragments instead....

Comment: I understood the problem, my code is working fine in a fresh new Activity but I'm calling this code from a Layout which is dispayed thanks to getLayoutInflater().inflate. any idea why My Spinners cannot be opened in a Fragment ?

Comment: also works well in fragment. maybe you did some things wrong in fragment